# Cant access IIS even through a random port

Tags: windows, iis

I have several servers from different countries that I want to configure IIS on them. I guess port 80 is blocked in all of them by the provider, but even when I added a random port from Bindings < Add Binding < port 7891, no connection were received

Note that I've tried allowing all connections for required ports in my firewall setting.

Is there anyway to lift this restrictions through outside the panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I use amazon servers, all I had to do was to enable my desired ports in my AWS panel, which 80 is blocked by default.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that your servers are not connected directly to the Internet, but via routers. You would have to configure all routers to redirect the traffic on port 7891 to the server.